# Significant differences in t-test but not in ANOVA

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, anova

I have a 40-subject design with 1 within-subject factor (Block; levels 1-10), and 1 between-subjects factor (Knowledge; implicit or explicit). When I test for differences between the two Knowledge groups (across all values of Block) using an independent samples t-test, the **difference is significant** (t = 2.32, p = .027).

However, when I perform an ANOVA using both my between-subjects factor and my within-subject factor, there is **no main effect of Knowledge** (F = 2.76, p = .105). This seems rather odd to me. I was thinking it may have something to do with having unbalanced groups (the two levels of knowledge have 27 and 13 subjects). Does anyone have an idea?